# UIScrollView not scrolling Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I've disabled all my auto layout, but it still won't scroll. I have many UIButtons on it and they are all linked to a Segue to be clicked so it can lead to the next page. I haven't added any code for the UIScrollView, and I'm not sure if you do or not. Here's a screenshot and the code I have for the scrollview scene,

```
   @IBAction func derecourtButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func myburghButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func edmondsonButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func healyButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func bormansButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func jackwaysButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}

@IBAction func horrackButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func mchughButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func youngButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func mitchellButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func testerButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func parrButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}


@IBAction func holdenButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "classtoperiod", sender: self)

}
```

Here's the screenshot of the main.storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMPKu.png

EDIT: I also need each button to have a value like an email, as it will send an email to whoever you select on the menu. Say you select maths, it will set the email recipient to "mathteacher@gmail.com" and so on.

Comment: did you set the contentSize of scrollView, if not then set it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollview's width, 2300) // height should be grater than scrollview's frame height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write Below code to start your scroll and check first that you delegate that scrollView, if not then first delegate it.

By writting code in `viewDidLoad()`   like this :

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

and then add below code to set your view size into the scrollView.Yet we given default size as 700 => height,but after you check it's working then set `yourViewName.contentSize` in height of the `scrollView.ContentSize`

Write this code in `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`
static scroll Height :

```
   scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 700)
```

Dynamic Scroll Height :

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: yourViewName.frame.size.height)
```

may this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it won't scroll. Your scrollView doesn't know what its contentSize is (I assume it's [0,0] now based on your setup), therefore it will just behave like a normal UIView.

That's why when working with UIScrollView on Storyboard, you should ALWAYS consider using autolayout and setting the proper constraints. It's a little tricky at first, but once you've understood the mechanism, you'll love it.